# Is it Possible do a dynamical title in the a navbar?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a title navbar which shows up on every page(TheNavbar Component). However, I would like to change the title based on the page. For example. I have a folder called projects and inside other one called _id and a bunch of pages that refers to this id. I would like to show the project name in all pages inside of this folder _id and persists the date in case of a refresh. Should I call my API and take the info inside of the TheNavBar component, every refresh and create a computed property?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible to have a dynamic title

you can do it through computed properties and make an api call in each page change to retrieve the title

```
computed:{
   title(){
     return this.$store.getters['getTitle']
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I call my API and populate my store each time that page is refreshed? Where is the best place to call the API, in my component called The NavaBar? Each page inside of the _id folder uses a different store module.